# Getting the following error " The build could not read 1 project and Non resolvablle parent error" when down mvn clean install

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

Hello I'm very new to yang, I tried getting used to it and followed this tutorial page on : http://sdntutorials.com/yang-to-java-conversion-how-to-create-maven-project-in-eclipse/#comment-21958.

> [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR]   The project org.opendaylight.controller.model:Yang-03:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/home/shrenik/workspace/Yang-03/pom.xml) has 1 error
>   [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.controller.model:model-parent:pom:1.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 11 -> [Help 2]

I'm unable to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<parent>` section from your POM.

I'm pretty sure you neither have a POM `org.opendaylight.controller.model:model-parent:pom:1.1-SNAPSHOT` in your local Maven repository (`~/.m2/repository`) nor in your Eclipse workspace.

Don't ask me why the blog post insists on adding this without explaining why and how to establish it.

Comment: I did remove it , but packaging tags gave me an error too which i had to remove. I tried going through the blog ahead but at every step I'm getting new errors. Is there a better tutorial I can refer. Basically I want to parse my yang file to Java and this was the only blog I found regarding the same. SInce I'm new to this I'm having a tough time resolving issues